# How can I log the start and stop connection with known WI-FI networks

Tags: wi-fi, logging

At the end of a week , I would like to see a log for **each connection with a (known) WI-FI network** I made with my Galaxy phone.

I automatically connect to different networks.

It would be nice to see the **time of start/end connection** for those networks I am connected to. This would give me an indication for hours spend at each place.

Anyone knows if this is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question until someone else shows me another application.

I have found the following one in the market : **[Wifi Monitor](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.rjj.android.wifimonitor&feature=search_result)**.

Time will tell whether it really does what it promises.

Still, if anyone has got some other software which does this, please let me know !

**UPDATE**

After trying this app for a week now, I can confirm that it works. When I enter/leave buildings with a known WiFi connection, the start and end of the connections are logged. This gives me an easy although crude way of hour-logging.